# Two way data binding not working for <select>

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am using  with  in Angular 5. I want to bind the complete JSON object on selecting the dropdown value. So I am facing the issue because of that, two-way data binding is not working for it. When I am supposed to edit the object, I am not seeing its type in the dropdown. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<select class="w3-input dropDown form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedTypes"  name="option" (change)="onSelectedType()">  
               <option *ngFor="let type of attributeTypes"
                [ngValue]="type"
                [selected]="selectedTypes.title === type.title ? type.title : null">
                {{type.title}}</option>
            </select>
```

TS:

```
this.http.get(this.localClient + "attributes?q[_id]=" + this.attributeId, { headers: this.rqstHeader })
              .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => {
                this.attribute.title = data[0].title;
                this.selectedTypes = data[0].type;
                console.log(data);
             });
```

Here, 'this.attribute.title is working fine as I have bound it to a textbox. But 'selectedTypes' not working as expected on Edit Mode.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 5.x *ngFor was remove, use [NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) Instead Of *ngFor.

**TS File**

```
this.ResponseFromAPI = [
    {name : 'Name1', value : 'Value1'}, 
    {name : 'Name2', value : 'Value2'},
    {name : 'Name3', value : 'Value3'}
];
```

**Html File**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="ResponseFromAPI" let-i="index">
    <option [ngValue]="item.value"  >{{item.name}}</option>
</ng-template>
```

Hope so it's help. :)

Comment: How was `*ngFor` removed in Angular 5 ? Do you have a source for that ? It is stil mentionned in their tutorial : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Comment: But in [value], I want the complete JSON object to be binded. So I dont think this would work.

Comment: Use [ngValue] or else value= "{{item.value}}"

Comment: @AshishKadam Just created a plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/A2fohCIsmY0I35S9Q9rZ?p=preview with Angular 5.2, using `*ngFor`. `NgFor` is deprecated, not `*ngFor` (yeah, their documentation is completely unclear regarding the star `*directives` ...)

Comment: The deprectated ngFor directive should  be the one you are using in your `ng-template`in your answer ?